# Inquiry form like on URL

Tags: forms

[image]
I need to make an inquiry form on my website. This [demo form](http://calculator.fereastracora.ro/calcul-pret-termopan) is what I need. How can I make this thing? I tried Formcraft and Gravity but I don't succeeded.

In the first time I want to choose the color and the type for PVC. After that, line after line, I need to choose few values (`Open type` is combo field, `L` and `H` are numeric fields in `mm`, and number of pieces is combo type). In the bottom of form I need two buttons (Another product line and Send). If I press Another product, another line appear to be filled.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be talking about multi step form. Multi step form mean a large form which contains different sections are divided into multiple step to finish the form easily and clearly. By this you can set validation and take them to where ever you want. Here's a tutorial to guide in the process:

> #### [Multi Step Form with Progress Bar using jQuery and CSS3](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar)
>
> Break your long forms into smaller logical sections and convert it into a multi-step form with progress bar. The form has 3 fieldsets containing the 3 different sections of the form. The fieldsets are absolutely positioned and only the first one is visible by default. Moving to the next section fades out the current fieldset using jQuery .animate() and brings in the next fieldset from the right. The reverse happens if the user moves to the previous section.

Comment: We collect answers, not links. Please, provide a solution, or at least, the basis of a solution in your Answers: see [answer].

Comment: i don't have reputation to comment, so i had no choice to give him a way.After reaching 50 i'll do this kinds in comment itself. Thanks

Comment: I removed the link i guess this is okay now:) @brasofilo

Comment: There's no problem in linking (unless you're spamming your own blog without explaining why), you can put it back! Better than saying "google it" ;) What's nice is to put a summary of what we're gonna find in the link case it goes rot (happens many times).

Comment: okay i got you. whenever i put a link i have to explain what is in the link right?

Comment: Thanks for your edit and encouragement. but still i'm afraid to put links. Because that may become link building as you asked. @brasofilo

Comment: It's simple, if you're linking to your own site/blog, you have to disclose this information. Whenever in doubt, consult the [help].